# Working with Ajax in Rails 4 app- Showing Dropdown Options using ajax call

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, ajaxform

I am trying to implement ajax in my rails app, A job category dropdown is present based on the selection the page shows jobs.Here i am facing the issue is when a  category job is selected all the jobs are shown by default.

```html
class JobsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :find_job, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_action :authenticate_user!,except:[:index]


 def index
  if params[:jobcategory].blank?
   @jobs = Job.where(active: true).order("created_at DESC")
  else
   @jobcategory_id = Jobcategory.find_by(name: params[:jobcategory]).id
   @jobs =Job.where(jobcategory_id: @jobcategory_id).order("created_at DESC")
  end
  respond_to do |format|
        format.html # show.html.erb
        format.json #{ render json: "testing" }
        format.js # show.js.erb
    end
 end
```

```html
dropdown.js

$(function(){
 $("#divNewNotifications").on('click', function(){
  $.getScript(this.href);
  return false;
 });
});
```

```html
_testing.html.haml

- @jobs.each do |job|
 %div{class: "col-md-3"}
  %div{class: "thumbnail"}
   %div{class: "caption"}
    %h3= link_to job.title, job
    %h4= job.company
    %h6= job.location
```

```html
index.js.erb

$(function(){
 $("#testing").html("<%= j (render("testing")) %>");
});
```

```html
index.html.haml

%hearder
 %nav.navbar.navbar-job
  .container{class: "text-center"}
   %div{class: "btn-group"}
    %ul.dropdown
     %a.btn.dropdown-toggle.btn-job{"data-toggle" => "dropdown","role" => "button"}
      Jobs
      %span{class: "caret",id: "dropdown_title"}
     %ul.dropdown-menu{id: "divNewNotifications"}
      %li= link_to "All Creative Jobs", jobs_path
      - Jobcategory.all.each do |jobcategory|
       %li= link_to jobcategory.name, jobs_path(jobcategory: jobcategory.name),remote: true
  
        
%body
%div{id:"testing"}
 = render 'testing'
```

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'errors/filenot_found'

  get 'errors/unprocessable'

  get 'errors/internal_server_error'

  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  devise_for :users

  resources :jobs do
    collection do
      get 'all'
    end
  end

  root 'jobs#index'

  get "/404" => "errors#file_not_found"
  get "/422" => "errors#unprocessable"
  get "/500" => "errors#internal_server_error"

end
```

Comment: You would need to show the actual view where the "#divNewNotifications" link is, and your routes. Also you might want to read up on how Ajax is commonly done. By passing JSON data, not scripts.

Comment: @papirtiger Hi , thank you i forgot to added it in index.html.haml .... I have updated it. Do we have to set the routes in routes.db for Ajax ? ,Also any idea how to solve this ? I am new to Rails & Ajax.

Comment: Add your `routes.rb`. Rails routes will respond to any request content type by default - so no, you don't need to set up special routes for ajax.

Comment: @papirtiger ho ok , I have add the routes.rb .... I have been trying to solve this , could you help me out with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting an event listener on the `<ul id="divNewNotifications">` wrapper and not on the links.

```
$(function(){
    $("#divNewNotifications").on('click', function(){
        $.getScript(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

If you pass a selector to `jQuery.on` it will handle the events for child nodes:

```
$(function(){
    $("#divNewNotifications").on('click', 'a', function(){
        $.getScript(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Ho my GOD it works !! Thanks a lot :) :) :) :) ...... i have been running around this past 4 days !! Thanks a Lot !!! ...You made my day !! thank you thank you :) ...This code means a lot to me... Wow thank you for your help :)